# Fast way to resize an image (Mixing FMX and VCL code)

Tags: delphi

I want to quickly resize an image (shrink/enlarge). The resulted image should be of high quality so I cannot use the classic StretchDraw or something like this. The JanFX and Graphics32 libraries offer high quality resamplers. The quality is high but they are terribly slow (seconds to process a 2000x1000 image).

I want to try FMX CreateThumbnail to see how fast it is:

> FMX.Graphics.BMP.CreateThumbnail

I created a FMX bitmap in a VCL application and tried to assign a 'normal' bitmap to it.

> fmxBMP.Assign(vclBMP);

But I get an error: Cannot assign TBitmap to a TBitmap. Obviously the two bitmaps are different.

My questions:
1. Are the image processing routines in FMX much faster then the normal VCL routines?
2. Most important: how can I assign a VCL bitmap to a FMX bitmap (and vice versa)?

Comment: High quality resizing is expensive. Very hard to believe that FMX could help. WIC is pretty capable too.

Comment: Why a downvote? The question provides all information necessary.

Comment: So typical for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Most games are doing high quality resizing on multiple 
(hundreds) images in REAL TIME. But, yes... I know... that's done in hardware :)

Comment: Depends on what you mean. They won't be doing the same sort of resampling that graphics32 is doing. You should decide what algo you want to use and find an implementation. I'd look into WIC.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Ok David. Thanks. I will look into that.

Comment: I also wonder if graphics32 has capabilities that you have not found yet. It has a lot of resamplers and I think they are quite customisable. Usually graphics32 is blazingly fast.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-I compared the resampler function offered by Graphics32 with JanFx and JanFx is better AND faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GDI+ scaling.

You can alter result quality and speed specifying different interpolation, pixel offset and smoothing modes defined in `GDIPAPI`.

```
uses
  GDIPAPI,
  GDIPOBJ;

procedure ScaleBitmap(Source, Dest: TBitmap; OutWidth, OutHeight: integer);
var
  src, dst: TGPBitmap;
  g: TGPGraphics;
  h: HBITMAP;
begin
  src := TGPBitmap.Create(Source.Handle, 0);
  try
    dst := TGPBitmap.Create(OutWidth, OutHeight);
    try
      g := TGPGraphics.Create(dst);
      try
        g.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQuality);
        g.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeHighQuality);
        g.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
        g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, dst.GetWidth, dst.GetHeight);
      finally
        g.Free;
      end;
      dst.GetHBITMAP(0, h);
      Dest.Handle := h;
    finally
      dst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    src.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Many thanks. I work on something different right now but I will definitively try it tomorrow and let you know how it compares to JanFX (the best thing I have found until now)!

Comment: @Z80 Which one is better?